# SVG file in safari 10.0

Tags: css, svg, safari

Im using some really basic svg elements on a site as background urls. They are simple coloured lines, nothing fancy. Trouble I'm having is that Safari 10.0 seems to want to render it blue as opposed to the orange colour it should be.

I have another which is black that renders fine, its just this coloured one.  The svg code for the file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="10px" height="1.109px" viewBox="0 0 10 1.109" enable-background="new 0 0 10 1.109" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect x="-29.667" y="0" fill="#FF6400" width="69.333" height="1" />
</svg>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts this?

Comment: So much code for 10px orange line…

Comment: Could you show screenshots?

Comment: CSS for the styling is

     color: #000;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: CaslonGraphiqueEF;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 65px;
     line-height: 70px;
     background: url(../img/orange-underscore.svg) repeat-x center 90%;
     display: inline;

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/k7z85.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: In response to the earlier comment on it being a lot of code, I'm not using it as code directly, its the code for the file. The svg is being used as an underscore and i need it as crisp as possible

Comment: Could you give a link to a real page (or codepen/jsbin/etc.)

Comment: try this https://codepen.io/kr-design/pen/jrpYAP